# Ruby, loop over array of variable names, apply method to each and replace variable value

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have an array of variables, each is an array of class name strings. I want to loop over each, and replace the values of those variables with the returned valued of a function applied.

I tried using `#map!` with object modification, but that doesn't appear to be working.

```
choose_one_classes = ["ramjet-transform"]
add_classes = ["btn", "btn-md", "btn-success"]
list_group_classes = ["list-group", "list-group-border", "choose-one-list"]

[choose_one_classes, add_classes, list_group_classes].map! do |var|
  var.join(" ")
end
```

I know I could just do this:

```
choose_one_classes, add_classes, list_group_classes = [choose_one_classes, add_classes, list_group_classes].map do |var|
  var.join(" ")
end
```

But I was hoping there was another better way. I guess technically what I'm trying to do isn't "great" because I should stick to not modifying variables a lot because good functional practices, threading etc. But I'm curious.

**Edit**

#### Expected Result:

```
choose_one_classes = "ramjet-transform"
add_classes = "btn btn-md btn-success"
list_group_classes = "list-group list-group-border choose-one-list"
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to include your expected result?

Comment: The problem is there isn't a good way to assign an instance variable by name in Ruby. Which is pretty much by design. You can't even do it with `eval` anymore. As you pointed out, what you're trying to do isn't "great." Perhaps if you could explain in more detail the problem you're trying to solve by doing this, we could help you find a better solution?

Comment: @Jordan, I think you meant "...assign a local variable...". I was initially thinking along the same lines, but your argument has to do with creating a local variable (which cannot now be done), not programmatically changing the value of an existing local variable, which is a different kettle of fish.

Comment: Yes, you're correct, I meant "local variable"!

Comment: If you found at least one answer useful, please consider selecting the one you found most helpful.

Answer (score 5):

`.map!` only affects this implicitly created array and is equivalent to the following code:

```
all_classes = [choose_one_classes, add_classes, list_group_classes]
all_classes.map! { |e| e.length } # all_classes is modified
all_classes # [1, 3, 3]
```

But you need to modify each array's member that you could only do with a bang-method (with an exclamation sign at the end). Such a bang-method doesn't necessarily have to be `.map!`, for example:

```
[choose_one_classes, add_classes, list_group_classes].each do |arr|
  arr.map! { |e| e.upcase }
end
choose_one_classes # ["RAMJET-TRANSFORM"]
add_classes # ["BTN", "BTN-MD", "BTN-SUCCESS"]
list_group_classes # ["LIST-GROUP", "LIST-GROUP-BORDER", "CHOOSE-ONE-LIST"]
```

But arrays have no method `.join!` because their method `.join` returns string instead of array.

Comment: You are modifying the elements of the arrays. The OP wants to convert the values of the local variables from arrays to strings, which is a different problem.

Answer (score 4):

My understanding is that you want to programmatically change the values of local variables. You could do that using:

- [Kernel#binding](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Kernel.html#method-i-binding)
- [Kernel#local_variables](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Kernel.html#method-i-local_variables)
- [Binding#local_variable_get](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Binding.html#method-i-local_variable_get)
- [Binding#local_variable_set](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Binding.html#method-i-local_variable_set)

as follows:

```
choose_one_classes = ["ramjet-transform"]
add_classes = ["btn", "btn-md", "btn-success"]
list_group_classes = ["list-group", "list-group-border", "choose-one-list"]

local_vars = local_variables - [:local_vars, :_]
  #=> [:list_group_classes, :add_classes, :choose_one_classes] 
another_local_var = 3

b = binding
  #=> #<Binding:0x007fcd39a10eb0> 

local_vars.each do |var_sym| 
  a = b.local_variable_get(var_sym)
  b.local_variable_set(var_sym, a.join(' '))
end

choose_one_classes
  #=> "ramjet-transform" 
add_classes
  #=> "btn btn-md btn-success" 
list_group_classes
  #=> "list-group list-group-border choose-one-list"
```

Notes:

- The local values of interest must be defined before any other local values are defined, so that `local_variables` will return an array of symbols for those local variables only (plus `local-vars`, which is removed, but not `another_local_var`).
- Pulling `:_` from the array returned by `local_variables` is only to make the code work in IRB.
- If you try running this in IRB, you'll need to reload IRB each time you run it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to do this a lot you could make a method like this.

```
def join_classes classes
  classes.join(" ")
end
```

then you would just call it like so.

```
choose_one_classes = join_classes(["ramjet-transform"])
add_classes = join_classes(["btn", "btn-md", "btn-success"])
list_group_classes = join_classes(["list-group", "list-group-border", "choose-one-list"])
```

that would give you this result.

```
choose_one_classes = "ramjet-transform"
add_classes = "btn btn-md btn-success"
list_group_classes = "list-group list-group-border choose-one-list"
```

But I have to ask, why not just do?

```
add_classes = ["btn", "btn-md", "btn-success"].join(" ")
```

or

```
add_classes = "btn btn-md btn-success"
```

seems like that is easier? Are you pulling in the values from somewhere else, like a database?